# JavaScript Epsilon when multiplying

Tags: javascript, numbers

I was thinking that equality in ES6 is closed case, like this basic example:

```js
x = 0.2;
y = 0.3;
z = 0.1;
equal = (Math.abs(x - (y - z)) < Number.EPSILON); // true
console.log(equal)
```

But it does not work in this(multiplying) case:

```js
x = 2.3;
y = 23;
z = 0.1;
equal = (Math.abs(x - (y * z))) < Number.EPSILON; // false
console.log(equal)
```

Am I thinking wrong? Is it only designed for plus and minus operations? How can I safely fix it (it is true when you multiple epsilon by anything bigger than 2)?

Comment: `(Math.abs(x - (y * z))) = 4.440892098500626e-16 = 2*Number.EPSILON`

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the value of `Math.abs(x - (y * z))` and `EPSILON` :

```js
x = 2.3;
y = 23;
z = 0.1;
equal = (Math.abs(x - (y * z))) < Number.EPSILON; // false
console.log(equal)
console.log(Math.abs(x - (y * z)))
console.log(Number.EPSILON)
console.log(Math.abs(x - (y * z)) == 2*Number.EPSILON)
```

To avoid this you should be checking the order of the difference , and compare it to `EPSILON`, instead of the comparing the actual value :

```js
x = 2.3;
y = 23;
z = 0.1;
equal = (Math.abs(x - (y * z)))/ Number.EPSILON < 10;

console.log(equal)
```

Comment: because that's what defines the order, i.e, `EPSILON` is `10^(-16)` and `10` just means the order is changing i.e, if it's greater than `10` then now the order is `10^(-15)`

Comment: in short, it depends on your definition of equal, if you think a difference of order`10^(-5)` also equal, then you should've : `10^11` instead of `10`

Comment: Are you sure it is not 2? Because if you compare it with 2, it works anyway. equal = (Math.abs(x - (y * z)))/ Number.EPSILON < 2; // true

Comment: it is `2`, try running the first snippet and see the result.

Comment: @user3078850 The point is that there's no silver bullet. Repeated floating point operations can result in errors that are several multiples of `Number.EPSILON`. You need to decide what is an acceptable limit for your uses.